# How to remove text within anchor

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress blog that uses woo themes definition theme. On the featured slider, text appears that says "previous" or "next" on each of the arrows only in safari on a mac machine.

Featured slider: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

What is the best way to hide the anchor text within this code? I've try a simple display:none but that hides the arrow.

```
<div id="featured-slider">
  <ul></ul>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: I would make sure you close your `<li>` tag or you might have some issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ePTC/2/)

```
$('.flex-prev').text(''); //you can also use .html('');
```

or use [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ePTC/1/)

```
$('.flex-prev').empty();
```

or Pure JavaScript

Use [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ePTC/3/)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('flex-prev')[0].innerText = '';
```

or Use [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ePTC/4/)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('flex-prev')[0].textContent = '';
```

and more

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ePTC/5/)

```
$('.flex-prev')[0].innerHTML=''; //you can also use textContent = '';
```

Comment: Could the slider be overriding the javascript every time it switches slides? I'm using the function in document.ready() in the head of the page.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('.flex-prev').text('whatever');
```

In you case, you would set 'whatever' to be a blank string.

Check out: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1):

Removes the text from the anchor link.

```
$('.flex-prev').text('');
```

But you could simply remove the text from the link without the use the jQuery

```
<a class="flex-prev" href="#"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer vanilla JS:

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ePTC/)**

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('flex-prev');

for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].innerText = '';
}
```

If there is really only one, you could also simply do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('flex-prev')[0].innerText = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
<a class="flex-prev" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
```